# SQL-запросы с count долго выполняются

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица (mysql) c полем `binary`. C ростом базы (1Gb) SQL-запросы с `count` начали долго выполняться. Как решить эту проблему?

UPD:

У этой таблицы есть поле binary

```
select count(*) cou from docs
where status_id=1 and language_id=1 and user_id=10
```

Comment: Хоть бы пример кода показали для начала!

Comment: запрос покажите)

Comment: Индексами.

Answer (score 1):

бинарное поле вполне может влиять на запрос

```
count(*)
```

считает общее число всех полей, а вот если сделать

```
 count(id)
```

то тогда запрос будет полегче! проверь!

на кусочек, но должно быть время меньше.

Comment: count(*) - конструкция оптимизированная мускулем, и она будет быстрее чем count(id)

Comment: но count(id) не выберет запись с NULL которых может быть много, а если ставится условие получить четкое значение кол-ва строк, то count(id)

Comment: не помоголо :)

Comment: id в индексе?

Comment: count(*) - считает общее кол-во строк.

count(id) - считает кол-во строк у которых id is not null

count(id) - требует обращения к raw данным ( если нет индекса по id )

count(*) - НЕ требует обращения к raw ( но условия могут требовать )

Answer (score 1):

Сделайте единый индекс по 3м полям (`status_id,language_id,user_id`) - и count(*) будет бесплатный

Answer (score 0):

User_ID я бы проиндексировал. Судя по всему, он имеет наиболее широкий диапазон значений среди трех указанных атрибутов.

Comment: Проблема в том что записей в самой таблице не так уж и много, вся проблема в том что таблица раздувается из за бинарного поля. Индексацию я сделал по нужным полям, особо не помогло.

Comment: Вообще ИМХО, не должно бы оно влиять на запрос :-(. 

А бинарное поле нельзя убрать в другую таблицу? В дочернюю?  Попробуйте без него.